# Failed to execute echo command in system() in INIT in root file system

Tags: c, linux

**Host**: Intel pentium 4,  RHEL 6

**Target**:  ARM Cortex A9 running linux with my own small sized rootffile file system

I developed a minimal initramfs filesystem following the instructions
here: [Minimalist Initramfs and Initrd](http://www.aclevername.com/articles/linux-xilinx-tutorial/minimalist-initramfs.html).

So my initrmafs has only following things:

1- console

2- init

The init is the binary having the following code:

```
* myinit.c
 * Build instructions:
 * ${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc -static init.c -o init
 * */

#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("Hello world from %s!\n", __FILE__);
    while (1) { }
    return 0;
}
```

This works well with the linux kernel and in the log message at the end I get a hello world message.

But what I wanted is that after printing hello world, the `echo`
command should work and do the following:

```
echo 10 > test.txt
echo "$(cat test.txt)"
```

So what I did is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

        int main ()
        {
           printf ("\n");
            printf ("Hello world from %s!\n", __FILE__);

system("echo 10 > test.txt");

system("echo \"$(cat test.txt)\"");

          while (1) { }
            return 0;
        }
```

I am cross compiling my code using the following command:

```
  arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static echotest.c -o init
```

Hello world is printing correctly but echo is not working as the content of the file i.e 10 is not printing.

**Note:** 
Please note that this time I have following things in my file system i.e  initramfs:

1- console

2- init (binary for second program)

3- test.txt (an empty file)

4- a folder bin having the binary `echo`

5- a folder bin having the binary `cat`

Aprt from these, there is nothing. The main idea was to have a minimal file system, having only things which are really needed for my aplication.

The binary cat and echo I copied from  a working linux system.

Kindly help me in correctly running the echo command as above?

**Update**

My latest code is as under where I am mounting /bin:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void  mount_sys() {
    if (0 != mount("none", "/bin", "sysfs", 0, "")) {
     perror("there is an error in mounting \n");   /* handle error */
    }
    printf("mounting successful");
}

        int main ()
        {

mount_sys();
           printf ("\n");
            printf ("Hello world from %s!\n", __FILE__);

system("echo 10 > test.txt");

system("echo \"$(cat test.txt)\"");

          while (1) { }
            return 0;
        }
```

Unfortunately this is also not working. The last two lines in the boot log message are:

```
mounting successful
Hello world from echotest.c!
```

Answer (score 2):

[`system()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) requires `/bin/sh` to be available.

If you want really minimal, use `fork`/`exec` instead. Shell constructs like redirection will then (obviously) not be available.

As a stylistic comment, always checking system calls for errors would be a good first start for diagnosing problems, even if there will be no sane way to recover.

Comment: Also `echo $(cat ...)` is monumentally [useless](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. Can you put a few lines of code to explain ?

Comment: echo $(cat ...) is putting the content of text file on the console.

Comment: Reimplementing `echo` and `cat` in C would be a lot simpler than the minimal partial shell reimplementation you are asking for.  It would help if you could indicate what you really actually want to accomplish.  Anyway, the Internet is full of `fork`/`exec` examples.

Comment: Yes, but so is `cat` alone. (The link is broken ATM but google for "useless cat".)

Comment: got your point now. One more question , do you think I need the mount function? Once I was using /sys in my root fiule system, at that time I had to use the mount function as in my code.